# GLib-Critical errors in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, gtk

I'm having a lot of trouble after upgrading to 18.04. Certain GUI applications that use the GTK library are failing to start, throwing the error:

```
GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 03:16:28.378: cannot register existing type 'GdkDisplayManager'

GLib-CRITICAL **: 03:16:28.378: g_once_init_leave: assertion 'result != 0' failed

GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 03:16:28.378: g_object_new_with_properties: assertion 'G_TYPE_IS_OBJECT (object_type)' failed
```

I went to test out if I could get GTK apps to work in python and that also fails. Trying the simple example scripts from the official GTK tutorial leads to import failures, particularly:

```
File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import gi
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gi'`
```

I've tried to reinstall all the appropriate packages to no avail:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall python-gi python-gi-cairo python3-gi python3-gi-cairo gir1.2-gtk-3.0
```

Comment: »» import gi «« : No "gi" → https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/python-gi/filelist ... But you can use e.g. `from gi.repository import Gtk` (example from the file GUI_Main.py : app-name = APP-Tool.)